# Powershell: Multiple replace and delete

Tags: powershell, replace, foreach

I need help with this script. I have slowly gotten this far, but need help at this point.

I need a script that will move text from the end of a section to to a certain point in the file, and then delete the moved text. The text that is to be moved has markers and so does the location. I need to be able to delete the text after the move. Also need to be done on multiple txt files in the same directory.

For example:

```
Sample Input .txt

A;1;1;####; (#### is the location (1) marker)
B
B
B
====-1234 (==== is the find (1) marker)
A;1;1;####; (#### is the location (2) marker)
B
B
B
====-5678 (==== is the find (2) marker)

After processing

A;1;1;1234;
B
B
B
A;1;1;5678;
B
B
B
```

The text file can have multiple groupings like this. Need to do this for each grouping from top to bottom. Here is what I have so far, it just moves the text and doesn't delete.

```
$file = "C:\Users\NX07934\Documents\Projects\23045\Docs\SampleData\*.txt"
$old = "\####" 

$find = Get-ChildItem $file -recurse| Select-String -pattern "====-*"

$split = $find.ToString().Split("-")
$new = $split[1]


get-childitem "C:\Dir" -recurse -include *.txt | 
select -expand fullname |
    foreach 
    { 
        (Get-Content $_) -replace $old,$new |
        Set-Content $_            
    }
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any help?

```
$text = 
@'
A;1;1;####;
B
B
B
====-1234
A;1;1;####;
B
B
B
====-5678
'@

$regex = 
@'
(?ms)(.+?####;
.+?)
====-(\d+)
'@

([regex]::matches($text,$regex) |
foreach {
$_.groups[1].value -replace '####',($_.groups[2].value)
}) -join ''

A;1;1;1234;
B
B
B
A;1;1;5678;
B
B
B
```

Edit: - to apply it to a collection of files:

```
$regex = 
@'
(?ms)(.+?####;
.+?)
====-(\d+)
'@

Get-Childitem -Path C:\somedir -Filter *.txt |
foreach {

    $Text = Get-Content $_ -Raw

    ([regex]::matches($text,$regex) |
    foreach {
    $_.groups[1].value -replace '####',($_.groups[2].value)
    }) -join '' |
    Set-Content $_.FullName
 }
```

Comment: that worked for that instance, but i need it to do that in multiple files. open the .txt search for ====-1234 and replace the #### with the number. there can be multiple groups in one file and multiple files in the directory.

Comment: Left an example.  It handles multiple instances per file.  You just have to set up a loop for your file collection.

Comment: i tried the snippet, and i am getting an error at the -Raw line:
`Get-Content : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'raw'.
At C:\Users\NX07934\Documents\Projects\23045\Docs\SampleData\PowerShellTest_Regex.ps1:11 char:32
+     $text = Get-Content $_ -raw <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand`